# php > html - parse #

Tags: php, parsing

Im trying to parse a 'hash tag' (#) from php into ascii as part of an url. 
I've tried escaping the character in every possible way and also tried using ascii/ampersand codes, but whatever I try, it doesnt output an actual '#' in the url.

Example:

```
print l('node/'.$node->nid.'/edit/2\#extra');
```

Ends up like:

```
http://local/node/212/edit/%5C%2523extra
```

Instead of:

```
http://local/node/212/edit/2#extra
```

I've tried searching the web using keywords like 'parse', 'echo', 'print' and 'escape' symbols in php, but to no avail. I'm sure one of  you coding gods can answer this simple question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) function

```
echo "http://local/node/212/edit/".urlencode("\#extra");
// Will output: http://local/node/212/edit/%5C%23extra
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this `l` function that you're using? It looks like its converting non-alphanumerics into HTTP entities to make them into valid URLs.

Just write `print "node/{$node->nid}/edit/2#extra";`.

If you *really* need to use `l`, and you're trying to append a page anchor, then do:

```
print l('node/'.$node->nid.'/edit/2') . '#' . l('extra');
```